# Selecting Certain Cell on CSV

Tags: python, database, csv, validation, export-to-csv

My company recently purchased a machine and I'm trying to find a way to store its data in a our data base, but first I need to clean up the CSV or Select Certain cells to write into a new csv. I'm currently Using Python 3.9XX

I need to extract the fallowing items for from this file. Serial number(Highlighted Yellow),Start time,End time, Pass-step,fail-steps, and Test Results.

If I can manage to select one cell it will try to do the rest on my own but im currently stuck trying to select the serial number and then writing into a new csv .

[**DATA FROM CSV**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJUj7.png)

```
import csv

# read CSV
csvFile = r"C:\Users\Hunter\Documents\Programing\Python\Measu Dev\11.csv"
f=open(csvFile,'rt')
myReader = csv.reader(f)

Headers = ['SerialNo','PartNo','Startime','Endtime','TabPassed','TabFailed','TestResult']

Serialno = []

with open( 'Processed.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
writer.writerow(Headers)
writer.writerow(SerialNo)
```

[**RESULT**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86210.png)

This is my ending result, I want to be able to store the serial number under its header 'SerialNo' but nothing seems to work on my end. I'm pretty new to this any help will be appreciated it.

thank you guys.

Comment: Please, don't post images of code, error, input, output, etc. Copy/paste as text here. Also fix indentation of your code.

Comment: Also, your input file doesn't look like csv file.